# How to install xapian with Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, python-3.6, xapian

I installed Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 on Docker using the `ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6` repository. Now I'd like to install xapian so I can use it with Python. I have not found any ready-made packages, so I am trying to build it from sources. I set `PYTHON3` and `PYTHON3_LIB` parameters to point to Python 3.6. During the build process I get the following error:

> ImportError: libxapian.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried xapian versions 1.3.7 and 1.4.5 without luck.

How can I install xapian?

Here's a Dockerfile to reproduce my error:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y python3-pip docker.io python3.6 python3.6-dev software-properties-common \
      python-software-properties build-essential wget unzip cmake python3-sphinx \
  && cd /usr/local/bin \
  && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 python
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

# install xapian 1.4.5
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl uuid-dev zlib1g-dev
WORKDIR /root
RUN curl --silent --show-error --fail --next -O https://oligarchy.co.uk/xapian/1.4.5/xapian-core-1.4.5.tar.xz
RUN curl --silent --show-error --fail --next -O https://oligarchy.co.uk/xapian/1.4.5/xapian-bindings-1.4.5.tar.xz
RUN tar xvf xapian-core-1.4.5.tar.xz
RUN tar xvf xapian-bindings-1.4.5.tar.xz
WORKDIR /root/xapian-core-1.4.5
RUN ./configure && make && make install
WORKDIR /root/xapian-bindings-1.4.5
RUN ./configure PYTHON3=/usr/bin/python3.6 PYTHON3_LIB=/usr/lib/python3.6 --with-python3 && make && make install
RUN python -c "import xapian"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Xapian library (`libxapian.so.30`) is being installed into `/usr/local/lib` by default, but Ubuntu doesn't know that it's been put there yet. You can tell it by adding:

`RUN ldconfig`

after installing the core (so before you change `WORKDIR` to build the bindings).

There's some helpful information about `ldconfig` and library search paths on Ubuntu in the answers to [this Unix Stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67781/use-shared-libraries-in-usr-local-lib).